# Display done org-habit habits in a different face

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, faces, text-properties, org-habit

I'm experimenting with org-habit and currently have `org-habit-show-all-today` set to `t` so I can see a habit even when I've done it for that day.  I'm doing that because I want to get the little reward of seeing the line of stars right away :-)

However, I also want to not have habits I've already done distracting me from habits that aren't done.

How can I display those in a different face, so I can make the text of the habit "greyed out"?

Investigating further, `what-cursor-position` with a prefix argument reveals (I've removed the properties other than the faces):

```
There are text properties here:
  done-face            org-agenda-done
  face                 org-scheduled-today
  mouse-face           highlight
  undone-face          org-scheduled-today
```

The face associated with `done-face`, `org-agenda-done`, is already "greyed out" (grey italic text), which is the face I want.  However, I think what determines the face is just the text property `face`, which is associated with face `org-scheduled-today` (medium weight blue text) -- that makes the text appear in blue, not grey or italic.

Something I don't understand the intent of -- though resolving this may not be needed to answer the question -- Why would these habit TODO items have face `org-scheduled-today` when they are not scheduled for today?  I think the following code (from `org-agenda.el`'s `org-agenda-get-scheduled`) is responsible for that, but I don't understand why that behaviour is wanted:

```
    (let* (
  ...
       (face (cond ((and (not habitp) pastschedp)
            'org-scheduled-previously)
               (todayp 'org-scheduled-today)
               (t 'org-scheduled)))
         )
      (org-add-props item props
    'undone-face face
    'face (if donep 'org-agenda-done face)
...
```

So I think `face` is set to `org-scheduled-today` ("Face for items scheduled for a certain day") because it's a habit that *appears* on today's date, even though it's not *scheduled* for today's date.

Here's the item in question (which appears as I've described above at the time of writing, i.e. when today's date is 2018-11-26):

```
** shave yaks
SCHEDULED: <2018-11-27 Tue 08:00 .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:LAST_REPEAT: [2018-11-26 Mon 11:23]
:END:
- State "DONE"       from ""           [2018-11-26 Mon 11:23]
```

Comment: This is fixed in org 9.3: done items now have face org-agenda-done